# Product of Homomorphisms into an Abelian Group is a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I'm having trouble understanding how to show that the product of a homomorphism into an abelian group H, from a group G is a homomorphism. First, the operation would be $fb(g)$=$f(g)b(g)$. I am wondering how to show that this operation is associative. Thanks!

Edit: I figured out why it is a homomorphism! Could anyone just help me show that the product of homomorphisms from G to an abelian group H is associative?

Answer (score 1):

The group operations (on $G$ and $H$) are given and are assumed to be associative.

The definition of a homomorphism is that the given *function* has to respect the respective group operations:
$$u(gh)=u(g)u(h)\quad\ u(e_G)=e_H$$
You only have to verify these for the product $u=fb$ defined above, using commutativity in $H$.

Comment: I got that part, but how do I show that the product of homomorphisms are associative. For instance, I'm considering homomorphisms f, b, and c, and need to show that $fb(c(g))=f(bc(g))$

Comment: It simply uses associativity in $H$ if you write down the definition:
$$fb(c(g))=(fb)(g)c(g)=f(g)b(g)c(g)=f(g)bc(g)\,.$$

Comment: From the formula you wrote it seems you want to mix the *composition* of functions with the *product* defined using the operation of $H$.

Comment: Ahh, apologies. I think I meant $(f*b)(g)=f(g)$○$b(g)$. That would be group operation for Hom(G,H) correct, where * is the group operation for G and ○ is the group operation for H?

Comment: Write down a proof that, for a group G and an abelian group H, the set of all homomorphisms Hom(G, H) from G to H is an abelian group. (Hint: you’ll need to explain why the product of homomor- phisms into an abelian group is a homomorphism, associativity, and what the identity homomorphism and the inverse homomorphism are. Most of this was done in class.) ---- This is the original problem. Am I mistaken with the group operation?

Comment: @RichardCao: Well, with the above notation of yours, if $\circ$ stands for the group operation of $H$, then $*$ is the group operation of $\hom(G,H)$.  1. Most importantly, $f*g$ is again a homomorphism $G\to H$, this is where commutativity of $H$ is used. 2. Associativity of operation $*$ follows by its definition and associativty of $\circ$ in $H$. 3. The unit element for $*$ will be the constant map $g\mapsto e_H$ where $e_H$ is the unit of $H$.